# C# Windows Form: How to transfer dataset to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I tried to find something that can solve my problem, but I havent found yet. So I would like to ask if someone can help me.
I want to export my dataset or datagridview (which I have populated from database) to Excel

here is my code on Load

> SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
>               try
>               {

```
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Persons", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds, "ss");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"]; ;

            // dataGridView1.DataBind();

        }

        catch
        {

            MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");

        }
```

I have a button to show in Excel "btnExcel", and there I don't know how to do?!

Comment: There are different ways to communicate with Excel and none of them is completely straightforward (like, for example, writing to a text file). You have to do your research, try something and come back here with specific doubts. Alternatively, you might post your exact requirements and request some help regarding the best methodology to accomplish what you want (BUT you should bear in mind that opinion-based questions are off-topic; so, in case of choosing this option, you should make sure that it does not fit in this definition).

Comment: One way is to write the table entries into a csv file and then issue opening excel with the file name specified programmatically, i think, excel will handle this correct.

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449233/export-datagridview-data-to-excel?rq=1

Comment: @icbytes you are right. And also this is a pretty easy way; but more than writing to Excel, this is writing to a text file (with StreamWriter, for example) in a format which is compatible with Excel.

Comment: That is one possibility.
 Directly piping to excel ? Do not ask me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425), it does not need any office installation vor creating a excel file. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/office/bb448854.aspx) are some tutorials from microsoft.

I hope it will help you.