# Export to Excel From 2 DataGridView

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I have `Form` like this

[image: My Image]

And I have a `Class` `Connect` to connect to my database. Here is the code:

```
class Connect
{
    SqlConnection con;
    public Connect()
    {
        String connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public DataTable executeSelect(String query)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        return dt;
    }

    public void execute(String query)
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I want to export to `Excel` from these `DataGridView`. In Excel file, I want the data position in rows and columns like this(for example): Data from these `DataGridView` are got from two Tables in Database.

[image: My Excel]

How to code this one? I'm already confused. Thank you before

Comment: try following this link....http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is already resolved **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182029/how-to-export-datagridview-data-instantly-to-excel-on-button-click)** and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449233/export-datagridview-data-to-excel). Try it and if you still can't, ask a question, there's a difference between asking for help and asking for code